# flutter forms subscribe to ANY validation change in validators to disable the submit button

Tags: flutter

How can I subscribe to any validation change in flutter forms?

I want to **disable** the forms submit button when any validator returns a "required" string.

I can sync all this manually by updating my own state object with the `_formKey.currentState.validate()` call in each `TextField.onChanged` function. Then set the submit to disable by default when nobody changes anything in the TextFields.

Is that the way I have to go?

In angular forms I can subscribe to validation changes :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [flutter_form_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_bloc), in this package each form is a `bloc`, so you can subscribe to any form change, and of course if all the fields are valid.

For disable the button when any field has a validation error, you must use a `BlocBuilder` with the `FormBloc`, and then simply use the `isValid` property.

```dart
BlocBuilder<SimpleLoginFormBloc, FormBlocState>(
  builder: (context, state) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: state.isValid ? formBloc.submit : null,
          child: Center(child: Text('LOGIN')),
        ),
    );
  },
)
```

`flutter_form_bloc` has other useful features such as listeners to navigate by reacting to the form state easily, asynchronous validation and more. Read the docs and see the examples.

This a minimal example for disable the submit button:

```yaml
dependencies:
  form_bloc: ^0.7.0
  flutter_form_bloc: ^0.6.0
  flutter_bloc: ^3.2.0
```

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_form_bloc/flutter_form_bloc.dart';
import 'package:form_bloc/form_bloc.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SimpleLoginForm(),
    );
  }
}

class SimpleLoginFormBloc extends FormBloc<String, String> {
  final emailField = TextFieldBloc(
    validators: [FieldBlocValidators.email],
  );
  final passwordField = TextFieldBloc(
    validators: [FieldBlocValidators.requiredTextFieldBloc],
  );

  @override
  List<FieldBloc> get fieldBlocs => [emailField, passwordField];

  @override
  Stream<FormBlocState<String, String>> onSubmitting() async* {
    // Login logic...

    // Get the fields values:
    print(emailField.value);
    print(passwordField.value);

    await Future<void>.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
    yield state.toSuccess();
  }
}

class SimpleLoginForm extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<SimpleLoginFormBloc>(
      create: (context) => SimpleLoginFormBloc(),
      child: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          final formBloc = BlocProvider.of<SimpleLoginFormBloc>(context);

          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Simple login')),
            body: ListView(
              physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFieldBlocBuilder(
                  textFieldBloc: formBloc.emailField,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Email',
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                  ),
                ),
                TextFieldBlocBuilder(
                  textFieldBloc: formBloc.passwordField,
                  suffixButton: SuffixButton.obscureText,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Password',
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                  ),
                ),
                BlocBuilder<SimpleLoginFormBloc, FormBlocState>(
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: state.isValid ? formBloc.submit : null,
                        child: Center(child: Text('LOGIN')),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: nice library will use it later still fighting with provider lol...btw. do you see any problem in using provider + your forms library?

Comment: You can use it with provider without any problem, if you have any questions you can leave it in the [repository](https://github.com/GiancarloCode/form_bloc/issues) and I will gladly help you.